# ee253 and assets205 upload and thumbnail view

Tags: assets

I have an assets custom field but I cant upload or view actual thumbnails in my S3 bucket. I update indexes but just see default jpg placeholder icons in the directory.
Any ideas what the issue could be? When I upload an image via my entry the progress bar completes suggesting a compete upload but the image never uploads. Tried jpg and png?
Thanks

Comment: Please consider rewriting your question with some paragraphs, and screenshots to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just responded to your email: the most common reason we see this is when system/expressionengine/cache is not set to 777 permissions - as well as its subfolders specific to assets.  Can you re-set those and try again after re-setting the permissions?

That should hopefully fix this up for you.

__

Edit to Add: If this is the same person I emailed, they resolved it by upgrading EE from 2.5.3 to 2.5.5.